# Azure Devops Release Pipeline: Can I Somehow Pass in a Service Connection to a Powershell Script?

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, cloud-foundry, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have a Powershell task that I use to perform several commands against a Pivotal Cloud Foundry instance.  Right now, I'm stuck passing in the `URL`, `username`, and `password` (as a locked variable) "manually" so I can `cf login` - but they already exist as a Service Connection.

Is it possible to "pass in" the Service Connection to access those values?  The `Cloud Foundry CLI` task, for example, has a dropdown for selecting a Cloud Foundry Endpoint. When I create a task group, if I add `$(someVariable)` anywhere, ADO is smart enough to add that to a list of variables that the task group requires.  I'm hoping something similar exists and I can say `$([ServiceConnection]cfConn)` or something similar in my Powershell script and magic will happen.

Comment: Did the following reply help you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you can kind of do that. You'll want to:

1. Go to **"Service Connections"** and set up a **"Generic" service connection** to use with Cloud Foundry. (We'll call it "Cloud Foundry - Dev" in this example)
2. After you've done that, you can set the service connection as a root variable:

```
trigger:
- main
pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest
variables:
  CloudFoundryServiceConnectionName: 'Cloud Foundry - Dev'
steps:
- task: CloudFoundryCLI@0
  inputs:
    cfEndpoint: ${{ variables.CloudFoundryServiceConnectionName }}
    cfCommand: 'YOUR-COMMAND'
```

However, if you're trying to log on multiple times in the same CloudFoundryCLI task, this route will not work for you. The task just uses a string to look up the service connection and set things up.

**Update: Including Classic Editor method**
To do this with the classic editor:

1. Go to the "Variables" tab within your release (or pipeline):
2. Add a **"ServiceConnection" variable**:
   [image: Azure DevOps - Service Connection Variable]
3. Head to your Cloud Foundry CLI task
4. Add **"$(ServiceConnection)"** as the service connection:
   [image: Azure DevOps - Cloud Foundry Task]

---

**UPDATE:** If you're looking to directly access custom variables within Powershell, and not the service connection, you'll want to create a new **Variable Group** within the **Library** in Azure DevOps:

[image: Azure DevOps - New Variable Group]

Then, you'll want to head to your pipeline (classic in the example below) and bind the variable group:

[image: Azure DevOps - Pipeline Var Group Binding]

Finally, update your Powershell script to use the variable:

[image: Azure DevOps - Powershell Variable Access]

Comment: I should have clarified - is there any way to do this in the classic editor?

Comment: Sure thing. I've updated my answer with how to do it with the classic editor.

Comment: That is EXACTLY what I want to do, but how would you pass in the `$(ServiceConnection)` to a Powershell task instead of a Cloud Foundry CLI? Powershell doesn't have a place to specify a cloud foundry endpoint like CF CLI

Comment: @Scott Baker In the case of PowerShell, you can access $(ServiceConnection) directly within your PowerShell task.

Comment: that didn't work for me - when I tried to access `$(ServiceConnection)` it just returned the GUID for the service connection, not an `object`.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood. You want to access the values stored within a service connection. You'd probably want to use a Variable Group to accomplish that instead of a service connection. You can't get the secrets out of a service connection.

Comment: This is actually the answer to my question - post it as such and I will accept it.